# Meteor not displaying data from collection in html

Tags: meteor

I am trying to get data from a collection in meteor and using a helper passing it to a template.

Here is my code in collection:

```
Meteor.publish('displayCustomers', function tasksPublication() {
  return Customers.find();
});
```

Below code in template JS file

```
Template.customerlist.onCreated(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('displayCustomers');
});



Template.customerlist.helpers({
    displayCustomers :function(){
        console.log(Customers.find({}));
        return Customers.find({});
    },
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="customerlist">
    <h1>All registered users</h1>
    {{#each displayCustomers}}
      {{fname}}
    {{/each}}

</template>
```

It is only displaying HTML content i.e. `<h1>All registered users</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Check that your publication is returning values to the client with this [MiniMongo chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-minimongo-explorer/bpbalpgdnkieljogofnfjmgcnjcaiheg?hl=en)

Comment: I added console.log at client end and same i can see in console tab in firefox

Comment: did you try the extension? It will show you what data the subscribe is retrieving

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure Customers is defined on the server and that your publish block is running only on the server.

Also I would toss a debugger into your onCreated block to make sure that your subscribe is being initialized.

Other than that, your code looks fine. I would try installing MeteorToys Mongol for client pub/sub debugging. https://atmospherejs.com/msavin/mongol

Comment: I added debugger inside publish and found its not going inside publish from collection js file. Below is my complete code

Meteor.methods({

Comment: Code didn't show up.  Try editing your original question. Comments have a character limit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually fetch documents in your template :

```
Template.customerlist.helpers({
   displayCustomers :function(){
       return Customers.find().fetch(); //will return an array with all published documents
   },
});
```